# Django + OWASP ZAP Cross Site Scripting (Reflected) - Is the value attribute of an HTML input tag a risk?

Tags: django, django-forms, xss, owasp

In my Django project, I have a search input in the navbar across most pages on my site.

I'm a beginner to OWASP ZAP. After running the scan, one of the high priority alerts (red flag icon) raised was [Cross Site Scripting (Reflected)](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/40012/).

In my case, this is my website search `form`:

```
<form method="GET" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="q"
         id="searchQuery" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" required="">
</form>
```

if someone searches for `javascript:alert(1);` in the search box, the `value=` attribute contains the same.

```
<form method="GET" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="javascript:alert(1);"
         id="searchQuery" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" required="">
</form>
```

Is this is a potentially vulnerability or is the input is being sanitized by Django? This form is created using a Django `forms.ModelForm`:

```
class SiteSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Search
        fields = ('q',)
```

Comment: Django's protection against XSS is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection). While it escapes HTML characters, it doesn't (and can't) change a value just because it could be valid Javascript. [This article](https://tonybaloney.github.io/posts/xss-exploitation-in-django.html) explores some ways a Django site can lose its XSS protection. I don't see a way to exploit this particular reflection (in a quoted `value` attribute of an `<input>` element), but the tool may be calling out any appearance of the reflected input.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks for your thoughtout reply. I read it when you wrote it and visited your links (and 100 others). I am still not clear how "serious" having a value's attribute showing a "malicious" query can be. I've temporarily decided to strip punctuation altogether from the query for now. I prefer not to do this since I like seeing the exact search query.